# List Comprehension to For Loop

Tags: python, list

I know its better/easier to do certain things in a list comprehension, but not all languages have such a useful tool.

So I wonder how they do it.

Take this example:

```
>>> mylist=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
>>> rows = ['\t'.join([str(v) for v in row]) for row in mylist]

>>> print(rows)

['1\t2\t3', '3\t4\t5']
```

What is the equivalent in a for loop (even though would be much more work)?

Comment: Basic steps: create a list to store the results, then write the comprehension in reverse (from right to left).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mylist=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
rows=[]   
for row in mylist:
    rows.append("\t".join(map(str,row)))
rows
['1\t2\t3', '3\t4\t5']
```

Without `map and join`:

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
rows = []
for row in mylist:
   s=""
   for v in row:
       s+=str(v)+"\t"
   rows.append(s.rstrip())
rows
['1\t2\t3', '3\t4\t5']
```

Comment: in this way, each row has a `\t` on its end, right?

Answer (score 2):

This one does it without using `join`, `map`, or list comprehensions: just for-loops.

Note how concise is the code when you use these very expresive tools, in comparison with the classic double iteration:

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

rows = []
for row in mylist:
    r = ''
    prefix = ''
    for v in row:
        r += prefix + str(v)
        prefix = '\t'
    rows.append(r)
```

Comment: You could remove the prefix variable and add `\t` in the back as I did :)

Comment: but that would yield `['1\t2\t3\t', '3\t4\t5\t']` instead of `['1\t2\t3', '3\t4\t5']`!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to print every element(list) in a single line and all element in the internal list separately by space.

```
for i in mylist:
    for j in i:
        print j,
    print
```

1 2 3

4 5 6

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension can be split out into the following:

```
rows = []

for row in mylist:
    temp = []

    for v in row:
        temp.append(str(v))

    rows.append("\t".join(temp))

print rows
```

Giving the same output:

```
['1\t2\t3', '3\t4\t5']
```